# List specific sheet names of excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a somewhat working solution to retrieve all sheet names from a excel spreadsheet without using macro's or VBA. I did find several solutions but they all required the file to be saved as macro-enabled spreadsheet or external tools.

My solution is this so far:
My First sheet is called 'First' and my last sheet is called 'Last'. In between I have several sheets with random names. These sheets in between have in the A1 Cell the following formula:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)&"\"
```

The first sheet has in B1 the following formula:

```
="\" &CONCAT(First:Last!$A$1)
```

And in B2 to Bx the following formulas:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($B$1,"\",CHAR(1),ROW()))),"",MID($B$1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($B$1,"\",CHAR(1),ROW()-1))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($B$1,"\",CHAR(1),ROW()))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($B$1,"\",CHAR(1),ROW()-1))-1))
```

To explain this:

```
FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($B$1,"\",CHAR(1),ROW()-1))
```

gets the occurrence of the the string "\" in $B$2 relative to the row. In A2 this is the first occurrence.

```
LEN($B$1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B$1,"\",""))
```

gets the amount of occurrences of "\" in $B$2

```
ISERROR(FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE($B$1,"\",CHAR(1),ROW())))
```

makes the values empty so dynamic named range can be created from it. I use the sheet for dropdowns and charts

For end-users I hide the first and last tab so they don't accidentally break the sheet. 
Somehow this all works, but maybe anyone has a better solution. It looks a bit overkill. Does anyone know of a better solution??

Thnx,
Jorden

Answer (score 1):

This is only an alternative:

in **A1** of each sheet enter:

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)
```

In **A2** of the first sheet enter:

```
=TEXTJOIN("*",TRUE,First:Last!A1)
```

In **A3** of the first sheet enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A$2,"*",REPT(" ",999)),ROWS($1:1)*999-998,999))
```

and copy down:

[image]

*(I don't know is this is any simpler.)*